# Recibir todos los item's guardados en mi database (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase

Así es como genero *item's* con un nombre diferente automáticamente en mi `database` de **Firebase** y lo mando a ella.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String FIREBASE_URL = "miurl";
    // genero un item distinto
    private String FIREBASE_CHILD = "item_"+ (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    EditText nombre;
    Firebase firebase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        firebase = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child(FIREBASE_CHILD);
    }

    // envio a firebase

    @OnClick(R.id.button)
    public void writeToFirebase() {
        firebase.setValue("Nombre:" + " " + nombre.getText());
    }
}
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero ahora cuando quiero recibir los datos en otra `clase`,  solo recibo el `item` que asigno en `private String FIREBASE_CHILD = "item";`

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String FIREBASE_URL = "miurl";
    // solo recibo el item que asigne aquí
    private String FIREBASE_CHILD = "item";
    @Bind(R.id.editText)
    TextView editText;
    Firebase firebase;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        firebase = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child(FIREBASE_CHILD);

        firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    // recibo en mi textview
                    editText.setText(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                    Log.e(getLocalClassName(), snapshot.getValue().toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo recibir todos los *item's* en distintos `TextView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo uso este codigo para recorrer todos los elementos de uno de los "hijos" de mi database en firebase. En concreto el hijo se llama fotos y una vez establecida "la conexion", cojo todos los hijos de este y luego los voy añadiendo a una lista:

```
DataSnapshot fotos = dataSnapshot.child("fotos");
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> fotoData = fotos.getChildren();

                for (DataSnapshot datos : fotoData) {
                    String c = (String) datos.getValue();
                    Foto foto = new Foto(c);
                    lista.add(foto);
                }
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias! Solucionado, he creado otra pregunta relacionado con *Firebase*, podrías ayudarme? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72124/c%C3%B3mo-borrar-items-en-firebase-desde-android