# ¿Cómo borrar "items" en Firebase desde Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase

He creado un `CardView` y lo voy rellenando con los datos que tengo en una `Database` en **Firebase** y hasta ahí todo perfecto, pero quiero hacer algo y no sé como.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para borrar los *item* desde `CardView`?

Lo que quiero realizar exactamente es borrar cada "item" al pulsar sobre el.

`Main2Activity:`

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference myref;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        myref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/prueba");
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder>(
                Blog.class,
                R.layout.individual_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                myref
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setNombre(model.getNombre());
                viewHolder.setAnos(model.getAnos());
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    }
    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        TextView textView_nombre;
        TextView textView_anos;

        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            textView_nombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            textView_anos = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.anos);
            }

        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            textView_nombre.setText("NOMBRE:" + nombre);
        }

        public void setAnos(String anos) {
            textView_anos.setText("AÑOS:" + anos);
        }
    }
}
```

`Blog:`

```
public class Blog {
    private String nombre, anos;

    public Blog() {
    }

    public Blog(String nombre, String anos) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.anos = anos;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getAnos() {
        return anos;
    }

    public void setAnos(String anos) {
        this.anos = anos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He visto tus preguntas anteriores, en este caso puedes hacer uso del método **[removeValue()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#firebase_removeValue)** del [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot), que en realidad cambia el valor a null.

```
  @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            snapshot.getRef().removeValue();  //Elimina valor!

        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias! Solucionado :) Pásate por aquí si puedes, gracias ! https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72200/es-posible-recibir-una-notificaci%C3%B3n-al-actualizar-la-base-de-datos-en-firebase